# Подключение двух монитов в Debian 64 на встроенной графике Intel HD Graphics 630

Tags: linux, intel, монитор, видеокарта, видеодрайвера

Имеется два монитора. Один HDMI, второй VGA. Подключил их к материнке GIGABYTE GA-B250-HD3P к соответствующим разъемам. И не могу настроить работу с двумя мониторами. Потому что система видит только один монитор (VGA), а на второй дублирует картинку.

Среда MATE, в ней есть виджет настройки параметров мониторов, но там виден только один монитор.

Вот что говорит xrandr:

```
# xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*
```

То есть, xrandr не видит что есть второй монитор. И пока он не появится, настраивать xrandr не имеет смысла.

Информация о железе/драйверах:

```
# inxi -F 
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-7700 (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB                                                             
        clock speeds: max: 4200 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 799 MHz 3: 800 MHz 4: 799 MHz 5: 799 MHz 6: 799 MHz                      
        7: 800 MHz 8: 800 MHz                                                                                              
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5912                                                                                            
        Display Server: X.org 1.19.2 drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)                                           
        tty size: 125x44 Advanced Data: N/A for root

# lspci -k 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 591f (rev 05) 
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5000 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5912 (rev 04) 
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000 
    Kernel modules: i915

$ glxinfo | grep display
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0

$ glxinfo | grep direct
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 

$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 256 bits)
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,

$ glxgears 
18471 frames in 5.0 seconds = 3694.190 FPS 
18775 frames in 5.0 seconds = 3754.955 FPS 
18064 frames in 5.0 seconds = 3611.438 FPS 
18966 frames in 5.0 seconds = 3791.963 FPS 
20396 frames in 5.0 seconds = 4079.017 FPS
```

То есть, драйвера из стандартного репозитария Debian вроде стоят правильно, рендеринг аппаратный. Проблема именно в том, что не видится второй монитор.

Лазил в BIOS, смотрел там, может где-то есть настройка какого-нибудь Multi Display. Ничего похожего не нашел.

Скачал intel-linux-graphics-installer-1.4.0 в сырцах, потому что сборки есть только под Ubuntu и RadHat. Начал читать документацию. Там пишут:

```
When releasing the installer you should note the following:
The installer should be configured with.
  ./configure  --with-config-uri=htt://…
```

Проблема в том, что в сырцах нет этого самого ./configure. Так же там внятно не написано, с каким URI надо конфигурять. И этот странный протокол htt... На этом остановился.

В общем, даже не знаю что дальше делать. Драйвера вроде работают, и их разламывать не хочется. Мне бы просто включить два монитора. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в опциях загрузки ядра была прописана опция nomodeset. Она была необходима для того, чтобы после инсталляции Debian Linux 9 нормально работал старый VGA монитор. Иначе после grub он показывал черный экран - ни процесса загрузки, ни иксов не было видно без этой опции.

После подключения второго монитора по HDMI я не догадался проверить, а будет ли он без опции nomodeset отображать загрузку и входить в иксы. Да, этот монитор может так делать, как я позднее выяснил.

Ранее я уже сталкивался с такой проблемой со старым монитором, но на драйверах NVidia. И эти драйвера могли с опцией nomodeset запустить иксы со своими проприетарными модулями.

Драйвера Intel сделать этого почему-то не могут. Если ядро запущено с опцией nomodeset, то аппаратная часть Intel HD Graphics 630 задействована не будет, останется только тупой фреймбуфер (об этом говорит строка drivers: fbdev в выводе inxi). А через фреймбуфер поддержки нескольких мониторов нет.

Решение в моем случае оказалось простым: убрать через grub опцию загрузки nomodeset, после чего драйвера Intel начинают нормально работать.

Унать, какой драйвер используется для рендеринга OpenGL, можно с помощью программы glxinfo. Если используется программный рендеринг через mesa на фреймбуфере, то вендор драйверов будет отображаться как VMWare (они помимо виртуалок делают еще и драйвера программной реализации OpenGL):

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor string"
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

Если заработали драйвера Intel, то вендор будет именно Intel, вот так:

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor string"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
```

По поводу сборки intel-linux-graphics-installer-1.4.0 из сырцов, то дело оказалось в наплевательском отношении инженеров Intel к документации. Документация не соответствует действительности. Для сборки необходимо воспользоваться autotools, после чего будет сформирован скрипт configure. Об этом моменте документация умалчивает. Правда, после сборки и запуска выясняется, что данный инсталлер не может работать с Debian. Пишет он следуюшее:

```
Checking if Intel graphics card available...
  • checking for i915 module in /sys/module
  • i915 module found
Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org...
  • fetching https://download.01.org/gfx/ilg-config.cfg
  • saving to /root/.ilg-config
  • fetched 1626 bytes
  • fetched 9818 bytes
  • fetched 12301 bytes
  • looking up [Debian stretch] configuration
Retrieving information from 01.org... OK
Checking distribution... Failed
Distribution not supported
```

То есть, данная программа поддерживает только Ubuntu и RedHat, и компания Intel бинарные сборки выкладывает готовые. Поэтому смысла в сырцах для самостоятельной сборки особого нет, так как на других дистрибутивах программа все равно драйвера установить не сможет.